# ibmcloud login command closed after providing credentials

Tags: ibm-cloud

The window of `ibmcloud` login command was closed after I entered my email and password.

1. I typed ibmcloud login command
2. It gives me https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
3. I type my pass and email
4. it writes ok and then it closed
   what I need to do?
   thanks

Comment: Add details: Which window, which OS, ...?

Comment: What were you expecting it to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: windows, it is possible to take some private lessons?I really try my best but I will glad to take some lessons, it will be very helpful for me

Comment: For future readers. The `ibmcloud login` authenticates with IBM Cloud. Then it stores credentials in the file `~/.bluemix/config.json`.